# PerformanceTweak.js(212,12): UCE0001: ';' expected. Insert a semicolon at the end

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Please help me guys, I have 1 error:

```
../PerformanceTweak.js(212,12): UCE0001: ';' expected. Insert a semicolon at the end.
```

Here is the line with error:

`int num = float.Parse(t);`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that is valid code for Unity, but if you want to write valid javascript try:

```
var num = parseInt(t);
```

JavaScript variables are not typed.

Comment: I've updated the code, give it a try :) please report back if it doesn't work and paste the error, it would help to understand what could be failing.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can not specify datatypes for the variable you are declaring.
Just type,

`var num = t;`

compiler is automatically going to recognize its data type.

Answer (score -1):

```
var num : int;
num = Mathf.FloorToInt(t);
```

this should work !